# Is it possible in Postgresql to use one column as source of names of columns?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose that we have table with field ID, type, Date, any_value

Suppose we have such values in a table (select * from my_table):

```
ID     type     date          any_value
1      alfa     2022-01-01    50
2      beta     2022-01-01    70
3      alfa     2022-01-02    111
4      beta     2022-01-02    444
...
```

Is it possible to create a query with a such result (if it is - how I may do it?):

```
date          alfa        beta      
2022-01-01   50          70
2022-01-02   111         444
....
```

Of course it should be performed automatically, not by making the simplest "left join" for each column (as the number of values in "type" column may be different in May , different in July- and it should be only one query.

(if it would be "gamma" in "type" column, then it should be "gamma" column after beta column, if "delta" - then "delta")

Comment: [Crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Comment: "*Of course it should be performed automatically*" - not possible. A fundamental restriction of the SQL language is, that the number, names and data types of all columns of a SELECT statement must be detectable _before_ the database starts retrieving data.

Comment: Thanks.  But may be ther is possibility to make stored function which can make such operation? I have to create such queries for 3 sets of values in "type" column but in near future it will  be necessity to make some more very similar - from a table with the same structure but another set of values in "type". And it will be 30..50 values in a collumn....

Comment: Sure you can create a function (or a view), but the restriction remains: the number, names and data types of the result must known before the database starts retrieving data